# doctrine query() params?

Tags: doctrine

i created a Doctrine_Query and executes it but i wanna know what params i can pass to it.

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
    ->select('cl.id, cl.name')
    ->from('ContactList cl');

$contactLists = $q->execute($params, $hydrationMode);
```

from the api documentation:

```
execute($params = array(), $hydrationMode = null)
```

where do they tell me about the params? and also hydration mode.

seems like i cannot find anything in the documentations. would be great if they had a reference for everything.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I beleive the params are an array of values to bind to the query - similar to a prepeared statement - for example:

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
    ->select('cl.id, cl.name')
    ->from('ContactList cl')
    ->where('cl.name = ?');

$q->execute(array('fayer'));
```

The hydration mode is one of the hydrator constants from `Doctrine_Core` and determines how the result set is hydrated (Array, object, etc..) You can also write [custom hydrators](http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_2/en/data-hydrators) if you need to.